# Always an Error on the First Message

Tags: javascript, python, html, websocket

Currently I'm working on setting up a basic WebSockets script. I can get the client to connect to the server, but whenever the server sends the first message to the client the client registers and error, and from what I can tell the readyState is open, and should allow the message to come through. The message has the correct beginning of /x00 and /xff. I can't figure out what's wrong.

EDIT: Here are the codes that seem to be causing whatever the error is. data.js just holds what the Python server used to set up the server so I only have to change one file when I test it out and the port hasn't timed out yet.

Client-side:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ws, error
init = function() {
  ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:"+port+"/websockets/main.py")
  ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log("Connected")
    log("Connected")
  }
  ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log("Received data")
    log(e.data)
  }
  ws.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    ws.send("Error occurred. Resend")
  }
}
log = function(msg) {
  document.getElementById("log").appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
  document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = document.getElementById("log").innerHTML+msg
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="log">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Server-side:

```
import threading, hashlib, socket, time, re, struct

class WebSocketThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, channel, details, websocket):
    self.channel = channel
    self.details = details
    self.websocket = websocket
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    print("> Received connection ", self.details[0])
    self.handshake(self.channel)
    while True:
        self.interact(self.channel)

  def finduser(self, client):
    for user in self.websocket.users:
      if user.socket == client:
        return user
        return 0

  def send_data(self, user, data):
    user.socket.send(self.wrap(data))
    print ("> Sent data", data, "to", user)

  def recv_data(self, client, count):
    data = client.recv(count)
    return data

  def handshake(self, client):
    shake = self.recv_data(client, 256)
    our_handshake = self.create_response(shake)
    client.send(our_handshake)
    print ("> Accepted client ", self.finduser(client))
    self.send_data(self.finduser(client), "Test")

  def interact(self, client):
    users = self.websocket.users
    this_user = self.finduser(client)
    data = self.unwrap(self.recv_data(client, 256))
    print ("> Received data ", data, "from", this_user)

  def create_response(self, data):
    key3 = ""
    lines = data.splitlines()
    resource = re.compile("GET (.*) HTTP").findall(data)
    resource = resource[0]
    for line in lines:
      parts = line.partition(": ")
      if parts[0] == "Host":
        host = parts[2]
      elif parts[0] == "Origin":
        origin = parts[2]
      elif parts[0] == "Sec-WebSocket-Key1":
        key1 = parts[2]
      elif parts[0] == "Sec-WebSocket-Key2":
        key2 = parts[2]
      key3 = line
    spaces1 = key1.count(" ")
    spaces2 = key2.count(" ")
    num1 = int("".join([c for c in key1 if c.isdigit()]))/spaces1
    num2 = int("".join([c for c in key2 if c.isdigit()]))/spaces2
    token = hashlib.md5(struct.pack(">II8s", num1, num2, key3)).digest()
    return "HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake\r\nUpgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Origin: %s\r\nSec-WebSocket-Location: ws://%s%s\r\nSec-WebSocket-Protocol: sample\r\n\r\n%s\r\n"% (origin, host, resource, token)

  def unwrap(self, data):
    return data[1:-1]

  def wrap(self, data):
    return ("\x00"+data+"\xff")
```

Comment: what is the error? and could u post the code thks

Comment: I can't read the error. All it is an error object, no message or anything. Which part of the code do you want? The client or server side?

Comment: Both would probably be necessary.

Comment: which client/browser version are you using? Which WebSockets server? Are you modifying the server (is that why you know the message starts and ends correctly)?

Comment: I'm using the newest version of Google-Chrome. I am using a function that adds the beginning and end of each message before sending so I know it's sent correctly. I'll edit the original message with the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove last \r\n after your token:

```
return "HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake\r\nUpgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Origin: %s\r\nSec-WebSocket-Location: ws://%s%s\r\nSec-WebSocket-Protocol: sample\r\n\r\n%s"% (origin, host, resource, token)
```

I'm sure it will solve your problem :)

Comment: Thank you so much. ^^ I swear all the examples I've seen had it. I was about to give up on figure it out. I guess it's the little things.

Comment: Had this problem too and searched nearly a week :D